# Find solution of problem Cauchy $y'=x^2-y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following Cauchy problem$$y'=x^2-y,y(0)=1
$$
I need to find the solution in $[0, 1]$ section.
I have done this steps to solve this problem:
$$y'+y=0,$$$$dy/dx=-y$$$$dy/y=-dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{y}dy=-\int dx$$
$$\ln|y|=-x+c$$
How continue solving this problem?

Comment: You may derive the equation a few times and use seperation of variables then. Or you use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved the homogeneous equation

you can use the variation of parameter to solve the inhomogeneous equation

$$y(x)=c(x)e^{-x}$$

Or use this approach
$$y'=x^2-y,y(0)=1$$
$$y'+y=x^2$$
$$(ye^{x})'=e^{x}x^2$$
And integrate 
$$ye^{x}= \int e^{x}x^2 dx$$

Comment: Thank you.I solve inhomogeneous equation.Solution is y=x^2-2x+2

Comment: yw @AsaturVardanyan +1 for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

So far you solved the homogeneous [linear ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) whose solution is $y_h(x)=Ce^{-x}$. Now you need a particular solution of  $y'+y=x^2$. Try something like $y_{\ast}(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where the constants $a,b,c$ have to be found. The general solution is $y(x)=y_h(x)+y_{\ast}(x)$. Then find $C$ such that $y(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**By trial and error:***

Observe that if $y=x^2$, $y'+y=x^2+2x$ and we have an extra term $2x$. Now try $x^2-2x$, that yields $y'+y=x^2-2x+2x-2=x^2-2$, giving an extra $-2$. Finally,

$$y=x^2-2x+2$$ and

$$y'+y=x^2-2x+2+2x-2=x^2.$$

Now with this expression $y(0)=2$, and to reach the imposed initial condition you compensate with the homogeneous part $Ce^{-x}$, picking the constant $C$ such that $2+Ce^{-0}=1$.

$$y(x)=x^2-2x+2-e^{-x}.$$

---

*Given that the RHS to obtain is a polynomial, the process is guaranteed to terminate (the extra terms will go in decreasing degrees).

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln|y|=-x+c \implies y= ce^{-x}$$

For your particular solution, let $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ and plug into your inhomogenuous equation to find  coefficients.

You come uo with $$y(x)=x^2-2x+2+ce^{-x}.$$

The initial condition $$y(0)=1 \implies y(x)=x^2-2x+2-e^{-x}.$$